# Error creating virtual device using android studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this error after creating new android virtual device on mac using android studio :

```
Name: Nexus_4_API_21

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /Users/Nicolas/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_21.avd
```

> Error: Unknown target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21' in
>   /Users/Nicolas/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_21.ini

I checked the path on error and it is in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You must have selected a faulty or incomplete (without Google APIs) `System Image` when creating the AVD. Delete this one and create a new one. When selecting the system image make sure you do not the the following message (in red) on the right side of the system image list where you select one.

[image]